# Run external program in parent Window without system()

Tags: c++, windows

How can I run an external Program within the parent Window without using `system()`?
Current Operating System: Windows 10

I tried using

```cpp
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", target.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

But it will run it in a new window instead of the parent Window.
(Target program is a Console Program. If Program has a GUI, open new window Instead)
What exactly I want:

```cpp
system("C:/Users/ELEMENT/source/repos/apath/aprogram.exe arg1 arg2");
```

But without using system();

I don't want to use system(); is because I want to learn if there's any other way to do it.
Please help!

Comment: Can you explain why not `system`?  Can you show a program using `system` that does what you want to do?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont
What exactly i want is:
system("C:/Users/ELEMENT/source/repos/apath/aprogram.exe arg1 arg2");
But without using system, I cant tell why don't use system. There is a reason for it..

Comment: Why's it a secret? If you can tell us what the problem is we can help otherwise ‍♂️

Comment: "I suggest you to use CreateProcess function:

Creates a new process and its primary thread. The new process runs in the security context of the calling process.

You can set the dwCreationFlags to CREATE_NO_WINDOW to prevent the process to create a new window."
I tried it, it doesn't work for console app.
Like for example I tried change program_path to "C:/Windows/System32/help.exe"
It doesn't do anything, but if I change the program_path to "C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe" it will work fine and open calculator

Comment: You probably want to create a process with redirected I/O streams, a question that has been asked and answered hundreds of times before. Though it's not clear what you want to happen if the new process creates a GUI. Apparently you want to reparent that. [Technically legal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) but it's not something you'd be able to do.

Comment: @yak Probably not. But maybe the OP doesn't want to use a broken ANSI C function that has no reason to exist. Like, it cannot cope with non-ASCII arguments. It cannot redirect the launched process' I/O streams. It cannot report errors with any sort of fidelity. And so on. If you think `system` works just fine you're probably using a garbage OS.

Comment: @iinsp What, you don't think the OP's 2nd cousin has a goldfish?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, isnt it off topic?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) function:

> Creates a new process and its primary thread. The new process runs in
> the security context of the calling process.

You can set the [`dwCreationFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) to `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to prevent the process to create a new window.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    const LPCSTR program_path = "C:/Users/ELEMENT/source/repos/apath/aprogram.exe";
    const LPCSTR cmdline = " arg1 arg2";

    // Start the child process. 
    if (!CreateProcessA(program_path,   // No module name (use command line)
        const_cast<char*>(cmdline),        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW,              // The process is a console application that is being run without a console window.
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```